# How to solve SQL Server Error: 15284? The database principal has granted

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Strangely one Login account does not exists in the server but it appears in the DB's users list. If I try to remove it, the error 15284 shows up.

I did some research and I did execute the following query:

```
select * from sys.database_permissions                     
where grantor_principal_id = user_id ('ca');
```

The result is the following:

```
class   class_desc  major_id    minor_id    grantee_principal_id    grantor_principal_id    type    permission_name state   state_desc
5       ASSEMBLY    65538       0           0                       5                       AL      ALTER           G       GRANT
5       ASSEMBLY    65538       0           0                       5                       CL      CONTROL         G       GRANT
...
```

As you can see (I hope it is clear) the object related to that is: `65538`
However if I try to get the name of that object:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(65538)
```

It returns: `NULL`

Does anyone know what is the best option in order to get rid of those records (sys.database_permissions)?

I will appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Have you checked in sys.assembly_modules, to see if this might be a CLR assembly? (`select * from sys.assembly_modules`)

Comment: This is DBA related question. Better you should ask on DBA exchange forum [http://dba.stackexchange.com/]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `major_id` column in `sys.database_permissions` is interpreted differently based on the `class`/`class_desc`. In this case, it's not an object_id, but rather an assembly_id (as found in `sys.assemblies`).

Comment: This code did the job: ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON ASSEMBLY::AssemblyName TO NewLoginName